# Geolocation: How to pass co-ordinates between Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project using React to create a weather app.

I am using [react-geolocation](https://github.com/tkh44/react-geolocation) to provide the latitude and longitude co-ordinates of the user's location. I then want to use these co-ordinates to inject into the [freeCodeCamp Weather API](https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/) to automatically generate the user's local weather:

e.g. `https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat={insert lat}&lon{insert lon}`

I have created two components to achieve this:

1. `<Main />`
2. `<Location />`

My issue is in passing the latitude and longitude co-ordinates from `<Location />` into `<Main />`. Please see my attempt below:

```
class Location extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Geolocation
    render={({
      fetchingPosition,
      position: { coords: { latitude, longitude } = {} } = {},
      error,
      getCurrentPosition
    }) =>
      <div>
        {error &&
          <div>
            {error.message}
          </div>}
        { latitude && longitude && <Main latitude={latitude} longitude={longitude} />}
      </div>}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        lat: null,
        lon: null
      }
    } 
    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat={this.props.latitude}&lon={this.props.longitude}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        // set state with response data e.g. this.setState()
      })
    } 
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            // Weather Data 
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

I believe this may be possible through the use of "props" to pass data from Parent (Location) to Child (Main) Component?

If this is not possible, I thought about using HTML5 Geolocation API.

All answers will be appreciated.

Comment: don't use react-geolocation as an extra package to your app, you can use html5 geolocation.

Comment: I did consider using HTML5 Geolocation. If so, would I call such code in the componentDidMount() method? And would I be able to insert the co-ordinates into the freeCodeCamp API through props?

Comment: of course you can

Answer (score 0):

You can get current location using `**Html5 Geolocation API**` and you need to add extra package to your app to increase app size.

Here is the example:

```
class Main extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    lat: null,
    lon: null
  }
    } 
    componentDidMount() {
     if (navigator.geolocation)
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition, this.showError, options);

}
  showPosition = (position) => {

        axios.get(`https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat={position.coords.latitude}&lon={position.coords.longitude}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        // set state with response data e.g. this.setState()
      })
    }
      }
});
}

  showError = (error) => {
    console.warn("Error", error);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // Weather Data 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**PS** check syntax errors if there comes any

Comment: Thank you for your responses, Sakhi - they are very helpful.

Comment: Is your issue fixed ?

Comment: I am going to try the solution tonight. I will let you know once I've done so. Thanks

Comment: sure. I hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Sakhi. The code solution you suggested works. So, thank you very much. My next task is to render the required data to be displayed on my page.

Comment: just use `setState` and display state values in render method. You can accept this ans.

Comment: but it depends what is in weather you want to dsplay?

Comment: I want to display the location, temperature, and weather icon of the user's current location.

Comment: e.g. `const weather = res.data.name`. `this.setState( { weather } )` for each value. Then pass `{this.state.weather}` into `render()`

Comment: You need to extract these infro from weather object and the display it in render, I would prefer if you get any error. Prefer to post a new question. So more user would be there to help you

Comment: Yes great. I will give that a go and if any issues I will re-post a further Q. Again, thanks for your help

Comment: and you should accept answer which are helpful in your issues. So others would be able to leverage of this,